# Inserting images in emacs text buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do we insert images in emacs? I am aware of:

```
(insert-image (create-image "image/path"))
```

And evaluating it with `C-x C-e`. I suppose I have to turn on the iimage-mode but it isn't working. What is the mistake in this method? What are some other ways of inserting images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full path to the image:

```
(insert-image (create-image "~/imagedir/...image..."))
```

Comment: Not stupid at all. To me it'd be logical for `create-image` to at least look for images relative to buffer's directory, but it doesn't seem to work that way. Adding the image to `image-load-path` didn't seem to help, either. I plan to investigate that and file a bug report.